# What does "俺も俺か" mean?

Tags: words

What does "俺も俺か" mean? Anyone please help me >__

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/870/meaning-of-pattern-x%E3%81%8Cx%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-y%E3%82%82y%E3%81%A0

Comment: Also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15930/7810

Comment: Perhaps you could supply the surrounding context for a more complete view of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

It means "Maybe, I'm to blame too".